# Filtering deeply nested array of objects in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in Mongo DB which looks like this -

```js
const clientsColection = { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec8492c27ecdc17362b86cb"),
    "clientName" : "data" ,  
    "users" : [
        {
            "roles" : [], 
            "operations" : [], 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecac60ab527bd0ba4a615cf"), 
            "isAdmin" : false, 
            "username" : "Adduser"
        }, 
        {
            "roles" : [], 
            "operations" : [], 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecac60ab527bd0ba4a616cf"), 
            "isAdmin" : false, 
            "username" : "new"
        }
    ], 
    "kpiObj" : [
        {
            "kpiName" : "epsilon", 
            "resultObj" : {
                "result" : [
                    {
                        "mark" : 4, 
                        "plz" : "01069"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "mark" : 5, 
                        "plz" : "01067"
                    }
                ], 
            }
        }, 
        {
            "kpiName" : "epsilon2", 
            "resultObj" : {
                "result" : [
                    {
                        "mark" : 3, 
                        "plz" : "01069"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "mark" : 1, 
                        "plz" : "01067"
                    }
                ], 
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

I am trying to perform a filter on a nested array of objects using `aggregate`, `project`, `filter` operators but I have not been successful yet in getting the expected output.

I want to achieve the following:-

- **stage 1**: matching the `users` array object for `users.username` and retrieving the matching array of objects (only 1 always).
- **stage 2**: match the output from stage 1 with `kpiName` in `kpiObj` and retrieve the matching array of objects (only one always).
- **stage 3**. match the output from stage 2 with `mark` in `resultObj` and retrieve the matching array of objects.

I've spent the last 3 days watching several tutorials and going through several stack overflow questions but hadn't been able to get the expected output. 
I've been able to get the expected output for stage1 by using following query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
db.getCollection("clientsCollection").aggregate([
    { $match: { 'users.username': 'Adduser' } },
    {
        $project: {
            users: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$users',
                    as: 'user',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$user.username', 'Adduser'] }
                }
            }, 'kpiObj.kpiName':1, 'kpiObj.resultObj.result.score':1 , 'kpiObj.resultObj.result.plz':1
        }
    }
])
```

**OUTPUT***

for matching `username` as `Adduser`, `kpiObj.kpiName` as `epsilon` and `kpiObj.resultObj.result.mark` as 4, I am expecting following output :-

```js
const clientsColection = { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec8492c27ecdc17362b86cb"),
    "clientName" : "data" ,  
    "users" : [
        {
            "username" : "Adduser"
        }
    ], 
    "kpiObj" : [
        {
            "kpiName" : "epsilon", 
            "resultObj" : {
                "result" : [
                    {
                        "mark" : 4, 
                        "plz" : "01069"
                    }
                ], 
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: In that example, what criteria should be tested against `kpiName`? What are you trying to get in terms of output documents?

Comment: @Joe :-  I've updated the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Filter for docs with possible conditions */
    {
      $match: {
        "users.username": "Adduser",
        "kpiObj.kpiName": "epsilon",
        "kpiObj.resultObj.result.mark": 4
      }
    },
    /** Re-create `users` array with new users array with only matching object */
    {
      $addFields: { users: { $filter: { input: "$users", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.username", "Adduser" ] } } } }
    },
    /** Re-create `kpiObj` array with new kpiObj array with only matching object */
    {
      $addFields: {
        kpiObj: {
          $filter: { input: "$kpiObj", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.kpiName", "epsilon" ] } }
        }
      }
    },
    /** Unwind (Split array into objects - here you'll have only 1) for flexibility to iterate over `kpiObj.resultObj.result` */
    {
      $unwind: "$kpiObj"
    },
    /** Re-create `kpiObj.resultObj.result` array with new result array with only matching object */
    {
      $addFields: {
        "kpiObj.resultObj.result": {
          $filter: { input: "$kpiObj.resultObj.result", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.mark", 4 ] } }
        }
      }
    },
    /** remove docs where there is not match on `kpiObj.resultObj.result` */
    {
      $match: { "kpiObj.resultObj.result": { $ne: [] } }
    },
    /** I would consider `kpiObj` & `users` as single objects `{}`, 
     * ratherthan array of single objects `[{}]`
     * Just in case if you need to be an array making object to array
     *  */
    {
      $addFields: { kpiObj: [ "$kpiObj" ] }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2fEFIMpLVPj)

**Note :**

You can use `$project` instead of `$addFields` to limit fields in each stage. As you wanted add this stage at last :

```
  {
    $project: {
      "users.username": 1,
      kpiObj: 1
    }
  }
```

or replace `$filter` with `$map` while iterating on `users` array & just return required fields rather than entire object.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is more than perfect :) 
Can you recommend some good tutorials over the internet that help can me introduce to these concepts of esp Mongo v 4.x?

Comment: @newbie : Check this :: https://university.mongodb.com , That's free & directly from MongoDB.